# How can I create materialized view using CQL and Java?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

How can I create materialized view using CQL and Java?

Comment: Just to let you know, materialized views were put back into experimental as they were not production ready. Try to steer clear of them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to just execute:

```
session.execute("CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...");
```